# Facebook can't scrape my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dns, web-scraping, asp.net-core

I know this question has been asked several times but I didn't find any solution to my problem.
I'm trying to make a web page rendering well in Facebook when shared, so I used the Open Graph Object Debugger but Facebook can't crawl my website at all.

It's an ASP.NET Core website hosted on a CentOS server. Don't know if this information is relevant.

I included the og-tags only **once** as requested by Facebook

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Export your Here Maps favorites to Windows 10 Bing Maps" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.jmevel.com/Resources/MapsFavoritesImporter.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.jmevel.com/MapsFavoritesImporter" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Here Maps favorites exporter" />
```

But I get sometimes this error 
[image]

and sometimes this one[image]

I've tried to share it to force Facebook to crawl this page but no results.

When I tried this Open Graph Object Debugger for the first time few days ago, I used the service **ngrok.io** to forward my local server when debugging and make it public. It was working well, at this moment, Facebook was able to scrape my local server through an ngrok.io address.

I've tried again today and it **worked only one time** but then I got the same error again however I didn't changed anything in my code (except the og-tag URL to match the good one). I have absolutely no idea why...
[image]

If I click on "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" it gives me a blank page.

My domain name is registered with OVH and my VPS is a Kimsufi (OVH also).
I've seen on [this page](https://www.adminlabs.com/blog/solved-facebook-doesnt-fetch-data-when-sharing-url) that Facebook doesn't like the CNAME DNS records. That's my case, by default I had this configuration:

```
www IN CNAME jmevel.com.
```

But OVH Manager doesn't let me change it to a A-record. I tried to delete this record but that wasn't a good idea because after that jmevel.com wasn't reachable for a moment.

I don't think that's a DNS problem anyway because this issue occurs even using ngrock.io to expose my local server online.

Thanks for your answers, I can't find any new relevant information about this on internet.

Comment: I currently only get the first error (Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED) only multiple tries to re-scrape the page. And that usually means it’s not a DNS issue, but your site is simply to slow to respond.

Comment: If I use CURL like Facebook does, it loads in 2 seconds. If I empty cache and load from my browser, it takes 7.58 seconds to be loaded and 2.57 seconds when I refresh the page. Assuming Facebook doesn't have any cache, why their server takes longer than 10 seconds to load my page while on my home connection it takes less than 8 seconds? And I'm far from my server because it's located in France and I'm in Taiwan...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue stayed for the last 6 months and I was still waiting an answer but it finally get resolved. I'm not sure what actually fixed it so here is the list of what changed since:

- I upgraded from ASP.NET Core RC1 to RTM
- I removed docker
- it's now served by an nginx server instead of exposing directly Kestrel
- I enabled gzip